# оконные функции postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

есть таблица:

1) `company`-название компании

2) `week` - номер недели

3) `ratio`- некая разница по сравнению с предыдущей неделей

4) `avgratio` - средния арифметическая разница за неделю по всем компаниям 
В таблице выведены те недели `ratio` которых > `avgratio`

если `ratio` было больше  `avgratio` 3 недели подряд то это считается успешной серией

Нужно вывести название компании и количество успешных серий.
Серии могут пересекаться, так если компания была успешна 5 недель подряд, то это 3 успешные серии, как показано на рисунке . По идеи  нужна оконная функция которая будет  скользить по неделям и нужно как то проверять что 3 недели шли подряд

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант: для каждой строки смотрим номер недели из предпредыдущей строки нарезав строки по названию компании и упорядочив их по номеру недели.

Если предпредыдущий номер недели + 2 равен текущему номеру недели, то это получается серия и мы проставляем единичку.

Далее мы группируем получившийся результат по названию компании и суммируем единички, чтобы получить количество серий.

```
select company, sum(is_series) series_count
from
(
  select company, 
    case 
      when lag(week, 2) over (partition by company order by week) + 2 = week then 1
    end is_series  
  from test
) q
group by company
```

[Sql fiddle пример.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b07c7/6)

Comment: да, вроде работает, спасибо!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)